# Additional action when insert a new topic on WordPress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, blogs

I have WordPress blog installed on my local machine.

I have a PHP code fragment. This code is independent with WordPress code, it works as a native PHP fragment.

My expectation is: Whenever a new topic is inserted into my blog, that code fragment run as adding a extra activity.

The problem is I don't have much knowledge in PHP, so I don't know which action is run when a new topic is inserted. Where do I should insert this PHP fragment?

Please help me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at WordPress's Hooks & Filters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters

Basically, these allow you to call your own custom functions when a WordPress event happens, so you'd put your PHP code fragment into a custom action or filter, then figure out which WordPress event should trigger it. You said "whenever a new topic is inserted"...not sure if that means a new category is posted or a new post is published, but there is a hook for just about everything. Here's a reference: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook

Comment: Dear, I mean "a new post is published", maybe created on website, or pushed from the WordPress app on my iPhone